# gcloud app deploy doesn't fail but doesn't deploy

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploy my GAE application via termina with the following command: `gcloud --project my-project-id --version staging app deploy`

It gives me no errors, the only output I get is:

```
Google Cloud SDK 183.0.0
bq 2.0.27
core 2017.12.08
gsutil 4.28
```

But the deploy doesn't actually work (I changed some text on one of the API returns just to see if it was changing in the actual URL I access).

Any idea what's going on or how to debug it?

EDIT:

I managed to get an error now:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Operation not allowed",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo",
        "resourceType": "gae.api",
        "description": "The \"appengine.applications.get\" permission is required."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

> DEBUG: (gcloud.app.deploy) Permissions error fetching application
>   [apps/darwin-ms-transfer]. Please make sure you are using the correct
>   project ID and that you have permission to view applications on the
>   project.

And I did check the permissions, I do have the `appengine.applications.get` permission based on the service account's roles.

Comment: Are you accessing the right URL? I mean, you are deploying in the *staging* service, not the default one, so your URL will not be `https://<PROJECT_ID>.appspot.com`. You can always check your deployed versions in the *Versions* tab in the Console; there you will be able to see your latest deployments and whether they are serving traffic or not.

Comment: What you mean by URL? you mean after deploying and trying to access the wrong URL? No, I am access the right one, but now the deploy step is actually failing.